# When adding content via post request, it returns undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on an educational project from udemy, by dr. yu. I am trying to add content via post request. I keep getting undefined.

From what I can tell, most solutions are user error based with post request and make sure postman form encoded option is checked, or not using body-parser. Both of those seem to be okay on my end.

The code successfully adds content, just, it's empty. Any tips?

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const _ = require("lodash");
const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/wikiDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });

const articleSchema = {
  title: String,
  content: String,
};

const Article = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);

app.get("/articles", function (req, res) {
  Article.find(function (err, foundArticles) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send(foundArticles);
    } else {
      res.send(err);
    }
  });
});

app.post("/articles", function (req, res) {
  const newArticle = new Article({
    title: req.body.title,
    content: req.body.content,
  });

  newArticle.save(function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Successfully added a new article.");
    } else {
      res.send(err);
    }
  });
});

let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 3000;
}
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port} successfully`);
});
```

Comment: What keeps returning undefined? Are you using [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating-using-save) for saving the object?

Comment: Can you post your html ‘form’ and also console.log(req.body) in your post route